# Active Choices Parameter with Credentials

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to get access to the credentials stored in Jenkins without having to hardcode them in the script itself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'GroovyAWSScMgr', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {
    return ["${env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"]
}
```

I've tried:

`return [AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID]`

`return [env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID]`

`return ["${env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"]`

`return ["${env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"]`

The result continues to be NULL

Comment: What was the result? `null`?

Comment: I added the fact that I get NULL in my post. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I guess you should not be able to extract the credentials. Probably the `withCredentials` step is therefore not forwarding the returned value from the closure and is declared `void`.

Comment: here's  the larger view https://paste.ee/p/RTo2x

Answer (score 14):

You can try this:

```
import jenkins.model.*

credentialsId = 'GroovyAWSScMgr'

def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
  com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class, Jenkins.instance, null, null ).find{
    it.id == credentialsId}

return [creds.username]
```

You can use `creds.username`and `creds.password` in you script.

I'm not sure if it is secure.

Comment: It works for me in jenkins scriptler, but when I try to add this code to script part of the parameter - nothing happens:
 `script:`
                `"""`
                    `import jenkins.model.*`
                    `credentialsId = 'xxx'`
                    `def creds =` `com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardCredentials.class, Jenkins.instance, null, null).find{it.id == credentialsId}`

                    `return [creds.getSecret()]`
                `"""`
I approved it in approver

Comment: Actually it works, my bad, I forgot to change the property `sandbox` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar in Active Choices Parameter for one of my jobs and nothing worked. I have instead used the below to prevent hardcoding credentials

Define your credentials, for ex. in your case `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` with appropriate values, as Environment variables in `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties` and retrieve them in your script

```
import jenkins.model.*

instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()

aws_access_key_id = ''
aws_secret_key = ''

globalNodeProperties.each {
  envVars = it.getEnvVars()
  if (envVars.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') != null) {
   aws_access_key_id = envVars.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID');
  }
  if (envVars.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') != null) {
   aws_secret_key = envVars.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY');
  }
}
```

You can refer them in your script as `${aws_access_key_id}` and `${aws_secret_key}`