# How to get credentials value inside CascadeChoiceParameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a requirement where I need to use credentials to fetch details, at moment I have to use username and password directly on below script section but I wanted to fetch it from credentials manager

```
properties([
   parameters([
       [
           $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
           choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
           name: 'EnvironmentType', 
           randomName: 'envtype-choice-parameter', 
           referencedParameters: 'Environment',
           script: [
               $class: 'GrovyScript',
               fallbackScript: [ classpath: [], sandbox:false, script: 'return ["N/A"]'],
               script:[
               classpath: [],
               sandbox:true,
               script: '''\
               //Need credential username and password here so that I can get value using that
               '''.stripIndent()
               ]
           ]
       ]
   ])
])
```

Answer (score 0):

- This answer requires having access to approve scripts **https://YourJenkinshostname/manage/scriptApproval/**
- I had to approve three scripts and I had to try to access the parameter in my job inbeetween each approval to get the next one to show up.
- It was also helpful to experiment in the
  **https://YourJenkinshostname/script** console

These were helpful to me as well:

- [Code Example][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379151/active-choices-parameter-with-credentials]
- [More Credential Class type examples][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205665/jenkins-credentials-store-access-via-groovy]
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DYy8.png)

```
def credentialsId = 'MyCredentialId'
def credsList = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class,
        Jenkins.instance,
        null,
        null
);

def creds = credsList.find{
    it.id == credentialsId}

/*
Fields shown for example purpose:
 println(creds.username + ": " + creds.password )
*/
```