# Work with Jenkins creds from groovy-script for parameter in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, credentials

I have a pipeline with dinamic filling of parameter (making request for BB Rest-API).
In code I am using token for authorisation in API:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            filterLength: 1,
            filterable: false,
            name: 'CHOICES',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: true,
                    script: 'return ["Check Jenkins ScriptApproval page"]'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: true,
                    script: '''
                        import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
                        def endpoint = "https://my.bitbucket.instance.com/rest/api/latest/projects/TEST/repos/monitoring/browse/ansible/hosts?raw"
                        def token = "132testtoken321"
                        def conn = new URL(endpoint).openConnection()
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
                        def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(conn.content.text)
                        def cut_json = response.lines
                        def optionsList = []
                        cut_json.each {
                            if (it.text) {
                                optionsList.add(it.text)
                            }
                        }
                        return optionsList
                    '''
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Print the Values') {
            steps {
                echo "Choice: ${params.CHOICES}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How can i use Jenkins cred in my script to hide token (CTRL+F "132testtoken321" to find it in code faster)?**

I tried differently:

1. Code:

```
def credsId = "Monitoring-rest-token"
def token = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getStore().getCredentials(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain.global()).find { it.getId().equals(credsId) }.getSecret().getPlainText()
```

2. [Jenkins Credentials Store Access via Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205665/jenkins-credentials-store-access-via-groovy)
3. [Active Choices Parameter with Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379151/active-choices-parameter-with-credentials)

But nothing worked
​